# VBA Counting difference between the first time value and the second time value, and move to next cell

Tags: excel, vba

My assignment is to find the time gap between two time, especially find out big gaps, you can see below. In the beginning,every time gap of column A is 1 second until 11:40. I want to find every time gap and mark them in the column B, I will find where is the big gap which over than 1 second.  Thanks.

```
Date            
4/27/2017 11:28:33  
4/27/2017 11:28:34  
4/27/2017 11:28:35  
4/27/2017 11:28:36  
4/27/2017 11:28:37  
4/27/2017 11:28:38  
4/27/2017 11:28:39  
4/27/2017 11:28:40  
4/27/2017 11:40:15  
4/27/2017 11:40:16  
4/27/2017 11:40:17  
4/27/2017 11:40:18  
4/27/2017 11:40:19  
4/27/2017 11:40:20  
4/27/2017 11:40:21
```

Comment: So what have you tried? This site will help you improve / fix your code but won't do it for you.

Comment: Why don't you use a formula or conditional formatting rather than choose VBA?

Comment: I just learned it yesterday, I tried to use loop but I don't think I used it correctly way. This is a small part of my project, I am the first one try to use VBA in my team. I try to use VBA because we have too many files need to work with, the volume a data is too big, I begin in a small part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates start in cell `A1`, in cell `B2` enter this formula `=(A2-A1)*86400` and drag it to the bottom. It will show you the difference between two times in seconds (you can round it to one decimal).